# React: How to catch onMouseUp event outside of canvas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that consists of a `canvas` and some mouse handlers to allow the user to draw a rectangle while the mouse is pressed. When the mouse is released (`onMouseUp`) I want the drawing to stop, so further mouse movements will not change the canvas.

This works as long as the mouse is released while it points on the canvas. However, if I press the button, move the mouse outside and then release the button, the `onMouseUp` event is not fired. So when I move the mouse back on the canvas, it continues drawing, altough it shouldn't.

What is the best way to catch `onMouseUp` events outside a component? Register a listener on `window`? Check if the mouse is pressed inside the `mouseMove` handler?

Comment: What about `onMouseLeave`

Comment: I thought about that. I could add a mouseUp listener to the document when onMouseLeave occurs on the canvas and remove it again onMouseEnter. Is that a proper solution? Or is there something more "react-y"?

Comment: Okay, I implemented it with `onMouseLeave` and `onMouseEnter`. Works pretty nice. Thank you!